# Scheduled AWS Batch Job with EventBridge Not Working

Tags: aws-event-bridge, aws-batch

What I am trying to do:

Use Eventbridge to schedule an AWS Batch job to run daily.

The problem:

I've created a rule in Eventbridge for a working AWS batch job., but it's is not being kicked off at the scheduled time.

The only thing that I can think of that is going wrong is maybe I don't have the correct role type, trust relationship and policy for the rule? Any help provided would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Role Information

Role use case type: Allows EC2 instances to call aws services on your behalf

Trust Relationships

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Permissions (related to EventBridge only): AWSBatchServiceEventTargetRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "batch:SubmitJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by [AWS-User-0570900] in below link:
https://repost.aws/questions/QUTY4nNS7jRMir8on3U8Ntwg/scheduled-aws-batch-job-with-event-bridge-not-working

Provided Role has following Trust Relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

And following permission in the Policy:

```
{

        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "batch:SubmitJob"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:batch:region:account-number:job-definition/our-job-xxxxxxx",
                    "arn:aws:batch:region:account-number:job-definition/our-job-xxxxxxx:*",
                    "arn:aws:batch:region:account-number:job-queue/our-job-xxxxxxx"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
    }
```